# Change CMakeLists.txt from rosbuild to catkin

Tags: ros, pcl, catkin, cmake, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!

I would appreciate if someone could help me correct this CMakeLists.txt from rosbuild to catkin!

Thank you for your time!

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

rosbuild_init()

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

# add dynamic reconfigure api
rosbuild_find_ros_package(dynamic_reconfigure)
include(${dynamic_reconfigure_PACKAGE_PATH}/cmake/cfgbuild.cmake)
gencfg()

rosbuild_add_executable(pcl_decimator src/pcl_decimator.cpp)
```

********UPDATE********

In the node of the package, there is an include which says it cannot be found:

```
#include <pcl_decimator/PCLDecimatorConfig.h>
```

The package only has one .cpp file in src folder, and has a .cfg file in the cfg folder... Why can't he found this? Is this a migration problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187752/change-cmakelists.txt-from-rosbuild-to-catkin/) by [anamcarvalho](https://answers.ros.org/users/19590/anamcarvalho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2014-07-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [migration guide](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild) does a fairly good job of documenting the migration process from rosbuild to catkin. There's even a [dynamic_reconfigure migration section](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild#dynamic_reconfigure).

For more details about how to use catkin and cmake, see the [catkin common tasks guide](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/catkin/html/howto/index.html)

**EDIT**

Your missing header is the generated dynamic_reconfigure header. You probably need to add an explicit dependency between your executable and the header generation, so that they get run in the appropriate order, as described in the dynamic_reconfigure migration:

```
add_dependencies(example_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anamcarvalho](https://answers.ros.org/users/19590/anamcarvalho/) on 2014-07-24**:
Hi! Thank you! When following the guide you sent me, I had to add in CMakeLists.txt the following line: find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp dynamic_reconfigure driver_base pcl_ros pcl)
I have now this error: Could not find a configuration file for package pcl.

What should I do?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-24**:
PCL changed quite a bit between Groovy and Hydro; the Hydro migration page describes most of the changes you'll need to make: http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Migration . You didn't mention changing distributions in your question, so I didn't think it was relevant.